# SharePoint-hosted SharePoint Add-in Features deployment

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-hosted-app, sharepoint-addin

I'm digging for a while into SharePoint-hosted SharePoint Add-in Features deployment, but I'm still dealing with some core questions.

I can write a UI add-in, consuming the REST API on any hostweb, that's very simple, some cross-domain calls js code and a .aspx page. In fact, to achieve this it does not require any add-in at all: it can be written in a js file to be consumed in a web part in the host web.

But, how do I deploy features?

I mean, how to deploy an add-in workflow to be used in any list having a title column (not list instance embedded in the add-in) I choose in the hostweb? 
How to deploy an add-in web part to be used in any host web web part page?

I've read some provider-hosted approaches, but can't find any roadmap to achieve such goals in a SharePoint-hosted add-in.

Thank you.